# rendering v-show based on if data does not contains "n/a" | N/A| NOT AVAILABLE

Tags: vue.js

I am leveraging vuejs and I have a v-html that displays some data. I want this data to only display if it does not have the words "not available", "n/a", N/A. If it has those words then the div needs to hide.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="metabar"><p id="spark" class="xx">Something:</p></div> <p v-html="selectedJob.OData__x0071_21">n/a</p> <br>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like

```js
checkHTML(html) {
  // check the html string with this regex pattern to see if it contains 
  // not available, n/a or N/A
  if (html.match(/([Nn]\/[Aa])|(not available)/g)) {
    // if it does include those words return false (hide the div)
    return false;
  } else {
    // if it doesn't include the words (yay!) you can return true (show the div)
    return true;
  }
}
```

then in your markup use it like so

```html
<p v-if="checkHTML(selectedJob.OData__x0071_21)" v-html="selectedJob.OData__x0071_21"></p>
```